# How to fix udev and upower problem

Tags: udev

When I'm charging my my notebook (Sony Vaio E series) and after I've removed the AC adapter since the charge is complete, the battery always shown that "fully charged" so I have write a script to manually do this every time:

```
#!/bin/bash
us=`id -u`
if [ $us != 0 ] ; then
echo "non sei root"
exit 1
fi
killall upowerd
(/usr/lib/upower/upowerd 1>/dev/null) &
```

But this is very annoying...there is an alternative? (like update udev/upower ecc)?

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is marked for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You don't give any information of the version you are running so I will assume it is 11.10. Have you recently upgraded all your packages specifically the package `indicator-power`

The latest version is 0.9-0Ubuntu-2 which has fixed some bugs. More details can be found at [Ubuntu Updates](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/oneiric/main/base/indicator-power)

There is some indicator issues with the battery indicator on 11.10 and many of these have been fixed in 12.04